# How do i get device id in Android?

Tags: android, webview, device

I am trying to have 2 things in my Android application.

Get the device id and then open a webpage with this id . eg `myserver.com/deviceId`

My main java class looks like this :

```
package es.unican.CityInfo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        //enabling Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //opening links in my webview. if you delete this line , any link pressed will cause the browser to start
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }


}
```

In order to get the device id i read that i should do something like this :

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

However i dont understand where i should place the android_id code as i always get an error.

The error is:

```
Multiple markers at this line:

- The method getcontext() is undefined for the type MainActivity
- Illegal modifier for parameter android_id; only final is permitted
```

Comment: Where are you call this method(Secure.getString(...))? Try to call it after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: I am calling it exactly there actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your error line with this:

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Do you know how can I obtain the same ID outputted by this directly from my phone? (for example, I wanted to obtain the IMEI i would just type: *#06# )

Answer (score 2):

```
private String android_id; // declared on top of class

android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); // called inside onCreate
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove private modifier and also don't use getContext() instead use getApplicationContext()
or simply getContentResolver()

inside your onCreate() method:

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Do you know how can I obtain the same ID outputted by this directly from my phone? (for example, I wanted to obtain the IMEI i would just type: *#06# )

Answer (score 1):

Use this line

```
 String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Since you are declaring string inside a method it will be scoped inside it.
You can get Activity context by using this.

Comment: Do you know how can I obtain the same ID outputted by this directly from my phone? (for example, I wanted to obtain the IMEI i would just type: *#06# )

Answer (score 1):

Change your line in code:

```
    getContext to getBaseContext
```

Comment: I tried this , it didnt fix the error. Thank you for your answer though

Comment: then use                                                       android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

    String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```